# Join differences between tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have one table called `cash_billings_bills_articles` It contains items from the original invoice, the another one `cash_billings_returns_articles` saves the new change history invoice or refund.

`cash_billings_bills_articles` data:
[image]

`cash_billings_returns_articles` data:
[image]

I need to do an join for get the following result:
[image]

Any ideas? Thanks

**SQL Fiddle**: [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d05c3/3)

**UPDATE:**

This is a little graph demostration what i need to do:
[image]

Comment: How did you pair cashbilling_id 41131 with cashbillingreturn_id 100 and article id 5699 (2nd row from top in the resultset)? Article 5699 is not in the returns table.

Comment: Article 5699 is obtained from `cash_billings_bills_articles` table, every `MIN` values of `GROUP BY(cashbilling_id, cashbillingreturn_id)` need to be compared with `cash_billings_bills_articles` if not exist then add this record for get diferrence.

Comment: I do not understand what you would like to achive, so no no idea. You have to describe in plain English what you want and how you tried to solve the problem.

Comment: So you have a clearer idea of what I'm trying to do is get the net Differences between invoices, comparing records of invoices. all begins by registering as `bill` invoice, then if it is modified changes are saved as a history returns. I tried many ways but do not achieve the desired result , that is why I have decided to ask for help here.

Comment: `cashbilling_id` are main doc number, `cashbillingbill_id` and `cashbillingreturn_id` are references numbers, so i want to get all the returns with their historic change for each reference. Considering that any bill begins having only one bill reference and returns multiple references in `cash_billings_returns_articles` table.

Comment: You may get some more help if you can take as an example cashbilling_id = 41131 and explain in english how the 2 records in cash_billings_bills_articles combined with the 3 records in cash_billings_returns_articles, result in the 4 records in the result.

Comment: @JRD first the query need to obtain `MIN` value in `cashbillingreturn_id` of every `GROUP` of `cashbilling_id` in result we will have: 100, 102, 103 AS `cashbillingreturn_id` this means the first return of this bill, then we need to take the `cashbilling_id` column for compare with `cash_billings_bills_articles`

Comment: Why is article_id 5699 not included in the 2nd compare, cashbillingreturn_id 101?

Comment: Because in the 1st compare has been totally removed or not exist in cashbillingreturn_id `100` that is the cause the record is in negative `-31.00`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a query that will get the result set as appears in your question. However, the business rules may not be fully implemented as it is difficult to decipher from just the output. Also, this may be better done in a procedural language, since it requires some calculations across rows.

It makes use of an left and right outer join and union to get all rows from both tables.

```
select cashbilling_id,
       ifnull(cashbillingreturn_id,min_cashbillingreturn_id) cashbillingreturn_id,
       article_id,
       total,
       diff,
       ifnull(cashbillingreturn_date,min_cashbillingreturn_date) cashbillingreturn_date
from(
      select cashbilling_id,
             ifnull(a_article_id,b_article_id) article_id,
             cashbillingbillarticle_total,
             cashbillingreturnarticle_total,
             ifnull(cashbillingreturnarticle_total,cashbillingbillarticle_total) total,
             ifnull(cashbillingreturnarticle_total,0) - ifnull(cashbillingbillarticle_total,0) diff,
             cashbillingreturn_id,
             cashbillingreturn_date,
             case when @group_id = cashbilling_id then @min_id
                  when @group_id != cashbilling_id then @min_id := cashbillingreturn_id
                  when @group_id := cashbilling_id then @min_id := cashbillingreturn_id
             end min_cashbillingreturn_id,
             case when @date_group_id = cashbilling_id then @min_date
                  when @date_group_id != cashbilling_id then @min_date := cashbillingreturn_date
                  when @date_group_id := cashbilling_id then @min_date := cashbillingreturn_date
             end min_cashbillingreturn_date
      from(
        select a.cashbilling_id,
               a.article_id a_article_id,
               b.article_id b_article_id,
               b.cashbillingreturnarticle_total,
               a.cashbillingbillarticle_total,
               b.cashbillingreturn_id,
               b.cashbillingreturn_date
        from cash_billings_bills_articles a
        left join cash_billings_returns_articles b on (a.cashbilling_id = b.cashbilling_id and a.article_id = b.article_id)
        union
        select b.cashbilling_id, a.article_id a_article_id, b.article_id b_article_id, b.cashbillingreturnarticle_total, a.cashbillingbillarticle_total, b.cashbillingreturn_id, b.cashbillingreturn_date
        from   cash_billings_bills_articles a
        right join cash_billings_returns_articles b on (a.cashbilling_id = b.cashbilling_id and a.article_id = b.article_id)
      ) q join (select @min_id := null as m, @min_date := null as d, @group_id := null as g, @date_group_id := null as dg) v
      order by cashbilling_id, -cashbillingreturn_id desc
    ) q
    where min_cashbillingreturn_id is not null
    order by cashbilling_id, cashbillingreturn_id, abs(diff)
    ;
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort in helping to solve my problem.